# Incremental builds not working with go build, only with go install

Tags: go, build

I'm running a project using Go Modules with 1.11.4 on Ubuntu, running in WSL.
My problem is that I'm having getting incremental builds to work as I expect. Perhaps this is due to me misunderstanding how it's supposed to, but I'd be glad if someone could clarify if that is the case.

Just as an example, if I do `go build ./...` then everything is built, as expected.
If I now do `go build ./...` again without any changes, my expectation was that due to the incremental builds, this time nothing would be built. But it builds *everything* again. I tried doing `go build -i ./...` (even though my understanding is that -i isn't needed anymore from 1.10), but the result is the same. This has been puzzling me for some time, as after reading the documentation I indeed expected the `go build` command to produce incremental builds.

The other day I realized that if instead I do `go install ./...` first, and then `go install ./...` again a second time, the second time around nothing is built, as I would expect. If I change a single module and run `go install ./...` again, then *only* that module is rebuilt, again what I would expect. So this gives me incremental builds.

So my questions are
1) Did I misunderstand `go build ./...` and how it handles incremental builds? Do I need to use `go install` instead?
2) Typically, we build the modules one by one, using the `-o` flag to specify an output path. Using `go install` instead, there is no `-o` option to specify an output path. Is there anything I can do to achieve something similar to `-o` using `go install`?

Thanks!